# What is the exact file storage size in the document directory in ios?

Tags: ios, directory, local-storage

I have to know the local storage in the document directory of an ios device. I had search and find out some solutions,but i didn't get the exact file storage limit of the document directory.Can anyone help me to find the correct answer? Please help...

Answer (score 1):

There is no storage limit as such, it is constrained only by the space available on the device. But your app might get rejected for storing data at wrong places. Refer to this for more details.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/ManagingFIlesandDirectories/ManagingFIlesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH6-SW1